# Reading state from the memory and update components

Tags: react-native

I have two screens which I am able to navigate between them. In one of them, there is a switch which I want to update its attributes after reading them from the memory via AsyncStorage! I am able to save its attributes,state, in the memory. However, when I close the app and reopen it, its status is not what I have saved!

This code for the switch:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["driverID","token","page","driverStatus"]).done((value)=>{
      this.setState({"driverID": String(value[0]).split(",")[1]});
      this.setState({"token": String(value[1]).split(",")[1]});
      this.setState({"page": String(value[2]).split(",")[1]});
      this.setState({"driverStatus": Boolean(String(value[3]).split(",")[1])});
      this.setStatus(Boolean(String(value[3]).split(",")[1]));
      console.log("driverStatus="+String(this.state.driverStatus));
    });
}
```

Here is the setStatus function:

```
setStatus(value)
  {

    let url = "https://hare.ebbyp.staging.c66.me/api/drivers/" + String(this.state.driverID);

    this.setState({driverStatus: value});
    AsyncStorage.setItem("driverStatus",String(value));
}

componentDidMount() {

AsyncStorage.multiGet(["driverID","token","page","driverStatus"]).done((value)=>{
  this.setState({"driverID": String(value[0]).split(",")[1]});
  this.setState({"token": String(value[1]).split(",")[1]});
  this.setState({"page": String(value[2]).split(",")[1]});
  this.setState({"driverStatus": Boolean(String(value[3]).split(",")[1])});
  this.setStatus(Boolean(String(value[3]).split(",")[1]));
  console.log("driverStatus="+String(this.state.driverStatus));
});
```

}

Comment: before you setItem, print the value, and make sure the value is right.

Comment: Short answer, no! However, when the value is correctly retrieved from the memory but does not affect the component! I think it is something related to render method!